# mysql, building long sql queries from form data. (php)

Tags: php, mysql, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I'm writing a large sql query based on information i'm getting from a submitted form that contains the search parameters.  I'm just wondering if anyone has any recommendations on the best way of doing this.  I was planning on having a list of if else statements and building a long search string based on the data the user enters search form.

Is there a better way of doing this?  Any recommended sites or tutorials out there?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the end goal? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. (btw:Yes, you *do* need to worry about sql injection: #1 trusted users aren't and #2 a non-malicious typo could break your app)

Comment: noted, change made. i'm building a dynamic search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll still need to worry about accidental SQL injection. Don't skip escaping user input.

As for actually building the query itself: It's not terribly uncommon to use php's control structures to concatenate a series of query parts, but many people find tools like [the Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) to be really handy.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) because there is no reason not to and I never trust user input.

If you have your variables in an array or an object, I would just loop through it and add the variable and value if it is set in the `$_POST` array. Note that I am looping through my array or object - not `$_POST` - which basically acts as a white-list.

You might need some additional checks for checkboxes that are changed and not set as they will not appear in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: in handling all the special cases a offical "prepared statement" was a bit over kill here.  "mysql_real_escape_string" worked in my case.

Comment: @Ray L. I disagree, using a data-access abstraction layer like PDO and a prepared statement simply is part of the evolution of php. There's really no reason not to use it as you can do the same as with the classic mysql functions and it´s not more work. It does offer you automatic security (no more `mysql_real_escape_string`), flexibility in choosing or changing your underlying database and flexibility in your error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Trust but check. It's simple escape all incoming parameters.

> mysql_real_escape_string